# How to convert an integer from base 36 to base 10?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to encode an integer as base 36, and then decode it to base 10. The encoding step is easy:

```
12345.to_s(36)
=> "9ix"
```

Now I'd like to decode that back into a base 10 integer. But this doesn't work:

```
"9ix".to_i(10)
=> 9
```

So how do I write

```
def base36to10(36)
  # ?
end
```

so that

```
r = rand(100000)
base36to10(r.to_s(36)) == r
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not converting from base 10, you're converting from base 36, e.g., in Ruby console or irb:

```
> "9ix".to_i(36)
#=> 12345
```

Paraphrased from [the docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i):

> Returns result of interpreting str as integer base *base* (between 2 and 36).

That said, isn't converting numbers between bases trivial? Iterate over the chars, multiply, add.